# Pig user defined functions not understanding what is eval function()

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to analyse the below code and was not able to figure out what is Evalfunction() and what it really does:

```
package myudfs;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
  import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

  public class UPPER extends EvalFunc<String>
  {
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            String str = (String)input.get(0);
           return str.toUpperCase();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
  }
```

Can someone explain me about the function ?

Answer (score 2):

Does a precheck to make sure the input is valid - if not returns null, otherwise it gets the first character of input, and uppercase just the first letter and returns just that upper-cased character. The try catch is there purely for the casting in case the input is not a string type.